# mddialog textarea model is not updated when changes in the main controller

Tags: angularjs, dialog, angular-material, customdialog, mddialog

This is a question about Angular Materials, mdDialogs and scope variables:

- I am subscribed to a specific topic using Stomp.
- Stomp receives Strings from the server that they are concatenated in a scope variable.
- User clicks on a button to show a mdDialog.
- mdDialog should show the incoming string changes in a textarea.

But...it is not working properly. I have to close and re-open the dialog to see the changes. I tried to add the textarea in the main view (index.html) and the textarea works properly.

Why doesn't it change the textarea when we are inside mdDialog in Angular Materials? Any idea to solve it?

This is the plunker you can see the main view (index.html) updates the random value properly, but if you open the dialog the value will not update properly...

https://plnkr.co/edit/teC69Sg7UqNbouHxpT22

```
var angularInstance = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']) ;

angularInstance.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ExampleCtrl($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $interval)
{
    $scope.randomString = "" ;

    $scope.initialization = function()
    {
      $interval($scope.addRandomChar, 1000) ; 
    }

    $scope.addRandomChar = function()
    {
      $scope.randomString = $scope.randomString + "a" ;
    }

  $scope.openMyDialog = function(ev)
    {
        var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  && $scope.customFullscreen ;
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: myDialogController,
            templateUrl: 'myDialog.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            fullscreen: useFullScreen,
            resolve: 
            {
                randomString: function ()
                {
                    return $scope.randomString ;
                }
            }
        }) ;
    }
});

function myDialogController($scope, $mdDialog, randomString) 
{
    $scope.randomString = randomString ;

    $scope.close = function ()
    {
        $mdDialog.cancel() ;
    };
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you create a Plunker or something as an example of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here you have a [working
>   plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bwi95jmqfZxHqhna6uZF?p=preview)

Summarising, I've slightly changed the way you pass the params from the `ExampleCtrl` to `myDialogController`, using **locals**.

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: myDialogController,
    templateUrl: 'myDialog.tmpl.html',
    targetEvent: ev,
    locals: {parent: $scope},
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    ...
```

Then, in your dialog controller, you have access all parent scope:

```
function myDialogController($scope, $mdDialog, parent) {
    $scope.parent = parent;

    ...
}
```

So finally, in the view you just need to bind `parent.randomString` to the textarea `ng-model`, and it will work as you expect:

```
<textarea ... ng-model="parent.randomString"/>
```

Cheers. Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :) It is working properly!

Comment: One additional question: In my code, I had to include "$scope.$apply()" after the field was updated (if not, Angular updated my text a few seconds later). The problem here is the dialog seems blocked when I try to close it. I think it is because "$scope.$apply" consumes too much time. Do you know another way instead of using "$scope.$apply()"?

Comment: I found it! $scope.$applyAsync ;)